# Are there any Ruby Interpreter/compiler to execute bunch of ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rubygems

I am looking for a interpreter or compiler tool which can help me to capture syntax errors of application built in ruby code and which should also integrate with Jenkins for CI and CD process.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "execute" or "validate/syntax-check"? Because for running ruby code, with all its dependencies, you just do `ruby my_app.rb`

Comment: Your question is off-topic because it is asking is to find a tool for you. That's what search engines are for. Also, your question is unclear: there are several interpreters and/or compilers for Ruby: Rubinius (technically speaking, this is not a compiler for Ruby but for a different language closely related to Ruby, but for most use-cases, it is close enough), Opal (same), JRuby, MagLev, IronRuby, YARV. MRI used to be popular, but is no longer maintained. Topaz ist still in development, but depending on your use case may be good enough. And there are one or two dozen not production-ready.

Answer (score 1):

Standard ruby binary can do that

```
ruby -c your_ruby_file.rb
```

#### Example

```
% ruby -c test.rb
test.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

For this file

```
# test.rb
count = 1_000_000_000
iter = 0

while iter <= count
  c = 1 + 2
  iter = iter + 1
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio...I have an application which is written in ruby. I want to execute all of the dependent rb files. Not a single rb file

Comment: Yeah well, look for all rb files in that app and syntax-check them individually using this technique

Comment: Attached my application tree structure for config folder

Comment: @Kally: yeah, I don't need your exact structure. What you need to do now is find all ruby files in a given directory and enumerate them, syntax-checking each. In ruby, for example, you can get a list of matching files by using `Dir.glob`.

Comment: Thanks Sergio... Actually I am looking for similar tools like Ruby-lint